Qt app running with Wayland has a bad drawing issue caused by backend problem?
So I'm working on a project, the Qt app running with Wayland and the OS is a customized Linux.
I run the Qt program with this env var QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext, this var makes my Qt app's CPU time reasonable and responsive, however, it makes one of my rectangle element unstable:

the rectangles above are the same one, screenshot at different times, screenshots show that it constantly varies width and height by 1 back and forth, no stopping.
The qml of this rectangle is:
Rectangle {
        id: xxx
        y:0
        width: 5
        height: parent.height
        visible: true
        color: "blue"
    }


I verified that no code is changing its width and height.
Simply removing QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext and using other values like QT_QUICK_BACKEND=rhi or QT_QUICK_BACKEND=openvg would make the rectangle stable but performance is very bad, CPU time becomes unbearable, so it's not a solution for me.
How to make the rectangle stable without compromising app performance? Thanks in advance!

What happens when you set QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1 ?

@StephenQuan I just tried, that doesn't work. I tried it with and without QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext, neither worked.
